# Is volatile needed for a lazy boolean shutdown flag in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Assume the following code

```
public class Singleton {

  boolean shuttingDown = false;


  void action() {
    if (shuttingDown) {
      throw new RuntimeException("already shutting down");
    } 
    // do some more stuff
  }

  // Called by a single thread only
  void onShutDown() {
    shuttingDown = true;
    // perform some more actions to remedy the class
  }
}
```

Basically I want to block all upcoming calls to `action()` with an exception.
I know that setting `shuttingDown` is an atomic operation. However the question is if I would need to make `shuttingDown` volatile to make the change visible to the other threads, which might be re-used from a thread pool.

I saw [this oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html) and also the javadoc on [AtomicBoolean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html).
However the latter [uses volatile](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.java#63), too. I set the value only once in a single thread, so I don't need the locking mechanisms provided by AtomicBoolean.
I just want to make the change visible to all threads as soon as the variable is updated.

As far as I understand the oracle tutorial, the update operation is *atomic*, that is no other thread can intecept while setting the value. The question is, *when* will the updated value be populated to the other threads (if at all?).

Comment: What about using `Thread.interrupt()` to signal the thread(s)?  I don't know whether the cost of a thread examining its own `interrupted` flag is less than the cost of examining a volatile variable, but maybe it's worth investigating.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is yes, you must make it volatile.

Although the operation is atomic, for it to be guaranteed visible to other threads you need to establish a happens before relationship. Volatile is the simplest way to do this.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid using volatile for performance reasons? It's actually a web application and the `action()` method is accessed once per request.

Comment: @user3001, Whatever provides the same visibility guarantee as `volatile` will have the same performance penalty as `volatile`.

Comment: @user3001 The best way is not to have a singleton :-). Does volatile actually cause a real performance problem? Have you measured it?

Comment: @user3001 You can probably leverage other synchronization that arleady exists in the request invocation logic. But it's probably not worth the trouble. This is very, *very* cheap.