# example javase pragram in 32bit JVM and 64bit JVM ,result NOT same

Tags: java, concurrency, jvm

There are two java main method :

The First :

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class StopThread2 {
    private static boolean stopRequested;

    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws InterruptedException {
        Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                int i = 0;
                while (!stopRequested)
                System.out.println(i++);
            }
        });
        backgroundThread.start();

        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        stopRequested = true;
    }
}
```

The Second:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class StopThread {
    private static boolean stopRequested;

    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws InterruptedException {
        Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                int i = 0;
                while (!stopRequested)
                    i++;
            }
        });
        backgroundThread.start();

        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        stopRequested = true;
    }
}
```

in my mac pro ,the result is
: the first pragram will be stoped after one second about ,and the second will be still running

and my java env is :

```
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-468-11M4833)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-468, mixed mode)
```

for the same code, i have test in 32bit jvm and 64bit jvm ,  result is Not the same ，why？

Comment: I assume that the programs are NOT running within the same JVM?  If they are, how do you start them?

Comment: Try making your flag `volatile`.

Comment: Or use `AtomicBoolean`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is volatile needed for a lazy boolean shutdown flag in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28304116/is-volatile-needed-for-a-lazy-boolean-shutdown-flag-in-java)

Comment: they both stop on mine, just tried them both

Comment: @JRowan: The point is that without `volatile` or some other memory barrier mechanism, there is no *guarantee* that it will stop.  It may, but it may not. No guarantees.

Comment: in 32bit JVM exec " java -server StopThread " in terminal result is : always running 
in 32bit JVM exec " java StopThread " in terminal result is : Can be stopped after

Answer (score 0):

`stopRequested` must be `volatile` in both cases. Otherwise the Thread you started may not see `stopRequested` updates made by the Main Thread.

Comment: In fact, I know that i can use AtomicBoolean or CountDownLatch or volatile or Synchronized to stop a thread.  BUT , The results of the run my Second pragram in 32bit jvm  or 64bitjvm   not same ,I wonder is this  ，is not how to stop a thread

Comment: in 32bit JVM exec "  java -server StopThread  " in terminal  result is : always running    
in 32bit JVM exec "  java StopThread  "  in terminal result is : Can be stopped after

Comment: @杨相国 If you knew that you could use volatile etc. why didn't you post that in your question?? That would have saved people a lot of time by not letting them give answers that you already knew.

Comment: oh  i am sorry ,i am a new user.  i just Don't understand 32bit jvm  ,-server and not use -server  ,it is different , you can test this

Comment: Concurrent code like above, ie which has logical mistakes from Java Memory Model perspective, may [or may not] produce some constant results depending on the processor architecture, JDK settings etc. 

For example you may look at [link](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html)  Multiprocessors, and how the support of barriers and atomics is different depending on the architecture.

Likely there are similar differences depending on JDK settings which may[may not] produce constant results for the same piece of concurrent code.